# Get to UIViewController from UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is there a built-in way to get from a `UIView` to its `UIViewController`? I know you can get from `UIViewController` to its `UIView` via `[self view]` but I was wondering if there is a reverse reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a view, how do I get its viewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372977/given-a-view-how-do-i-get-its-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since this has been the accepted answer for a long time, I feel I need to rectify it with a better answer.

Some comments on the need:

- Your view should not need to access the view controller directly.
- The view should instead be independent of the view controller, and be able to work in different contexts.
- Should you need the view to interface in a way with the view controller, the recommended way, and what Apple does across Cocoa is to use the delegate pattern.

An example of how to implement it follows:

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate < NSObject >

- (void)viewActionHappened;

@end

@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) MyViewDelegate delegate;

@end

@interface MyViewController < MyViewDelegate >

@end
```

The view interfaces with its delegate (as `UITableView` does, for instance) and it doesn't care if its implemented in the view controller or in any other class that you end up using.

My original answer follows: *I don't recommend this, neither the rest of the answers where direct access to the view controller is achieved*

There is no built-in way to do it. While you can get around it by adding a `IBOutlet` on the `UIView` and connecting these in Interface Builder, this is not recommended. The view should not know about the view controller. Instead, you should do as @Phil M suggests and create a protocol to be used as the delegate.

Comment: That's very bad advice. You shouldn't reference a view controller from a view

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: Wouldn't setting property to "assign" resolve the circular reference and resolve the problems with this approach?

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert, so are you saying Apple's very own BubbleLevel Xcode example app is bad? [`LevelView`](http://bit.ly/jh3gME) has an assign property to its `viewController`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: yes, it's bad design.

Comment: @Phillipe Leybaert I'm curious to know your thoughts on the best design for a button click event which should invoke some action on the controller, without the view holding a reference to the controller. Thanks

Comment: I have a view that is made from a viewcontroller that is used as a subview in a table. For efficiency, the view can be recycled, but I would need to update the represented object. In this case would it make sense for the view to be able to pull in the original controller?

Comment: It's a big smell... Is your view a `UITableViewCell` subclass? How is it reused? I'm guessing the view controller is responsible for reusing it, and thus might be able to update the represented object at the same time.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Apple's example projects tend to demonstrate usage of particular API features. Many I have referred to sacrifice good or scalable design in order to provide a concise demonstration of the topic. It took me a long time to realise this and while it makes sense, I find it unfortunate. I think a lot of developers take these pragmatic projects as Apple's guide to best design practice, which I am quite certain they are not.

Comment: While I agree that the view should not know about its controller in normal situations, I think it can still be useful when in LLDB, in the same manner as in normal situations the view should not care about its grandchildren, yet there still exists the `recursiveDescription` private method.

Comment: Agreed.  Regardless of whether it's bad form, it can be useful to know how to do this in debugging situations.  Also, OP didn't ask if it was a good idea or not.

Comment: Obtaining a reference to the view controller appears to be the only way to get to the top or bottom layout guide. Even Apple's documentation for the "topLayoutGuide" property of UIViewController suggests doing this. I tried to include the relevant code snippet but I couldn't get the formatting right.

Comment: @GregBrown assuming the `MyView` delegate will be the View Controller, I don't see why you can't add a method to `MyViewDelegate` to get the `topLayoutGuide` and have the delegate return that. Interesting point, anyway, that this is suggested on Apple Docs.

Comment: All this bs about "you shouldn't do this" is just that.  If a view wants to know about its view controller, that is up to the programmer to decide.  period.

Comment: Phil M does not seem to have created any protocol in his current answer. He wrote a category to the `UIView` class.

Answer (score 207):

Using the example posted by Brock, I modified it so that it is a category of UIView instead UIViewController and made it recursive so that any subview can (hopefully) find the parent UIViewController.

```
@interface UIView (FindUIViewController)
- (UIViewController *) firstAvailableUIViewController;
@end

@implementation UIView (FindUIViewController)
- (UIViewController *) firstAvailableUIViewController {
    UIResponder *responder = [self nextResponder];
    while (responder != nil) {
        if ([responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            return (UIViewController *)responder;
        }
        responder = [responder nextResponder];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

To use this code, add it into an new class file (I named mine "UIKitCategories") and remove the class data... copy the @interface into the header, and the @implementation into the .m file.  Then in your project, #import "UIKitCategories.h" and use within the UIView code:

```
// from a UIView subclass... returns nil if UIViewController not available
UIViewController * myController = [self firstAvailableUIViewController];
```

Comment: And one reason you need to allow the UIView to be aware of its UIViewController is when you have custom UIView subclasses that need to push a modal view/dialog.

Comment: Awesome , I had to access my ViewController to display a custom popup which is created by a subview

Comment: Isn't this bad practice for a UIView to push a modal view? I'm doing this right now but I feel it's not the right thing to do..

Comment: What a shame this is not picked as the best answer.

Comment: Phil, your custom view should call a delegate method which the view controller listens to and then it pushes from there.

Comment: `-traverseResponderChainForUIViewController`'s return type should just be UIViewController; you don't need the other method. `-firstAvailableUIViewController` is probably a better name. And it will break for things which override `-nextResponder`, but I'm not actually aware of any...

Answer (score 116):

`UIView` is a subclass of `UIResponder`. `UIResponder` lays out the method `-nextResponder` with an implementation that returns `nil`. `UIView` overrides this method, as documented in `UIResponder` (for some reason instead of in `UIView`) as follows: if the view has a view controller, it is returned by `-nextResponder`. If there is no view controller, the method will return the superview.

Add this to your project and you're ready to roll.

```
@interface UIView (APIFix)
- (UIViewController *)viewController;
@end

@implementation UIView (APIFix)

- (UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([self.nextResponder isKindOfClass:UIViewController.class])
        return (UIViewController *)self.nextResponder;
    else
        return nil;
}
@end
```

Now `UIView` has a working method for returning the view controller.

Comment: This will only work if there is nothing in the responder chain between the receiving `UIView` and the `UIViewController`.  Phil M's answer featuring recursion is the way to go.

Answer (score 35):

I would suggest a more lightweight approach for traversing the complete responder chain without having to add a category on UIView:

```
@implementation MyUIViewSubclass

- (UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while (![responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        responder = [responder nextResponder];
        if (nil == responder) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (UIViewController *)responder;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 22):

Combining several already given answers, I'm shipping on it as well with my implementation:

```
@implementation UIView (AppNameAdditions)

- (UIViewController *)appName_viewController {
    /// Finds the view's view controller.

    // Take the view controller class object here and avoid sending the same message iteratively unnecessarily.
    Class vcc = [UIViewController class];

    // Traverse responder chain. Return first found view controller, which will be the view's view controller.
    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]))
        if ([responder isKindOfClass: vcc])
            return (UIViewController *)responder;

    // If the view controller isn't found, return nil.
    return nil;
}

@end
```

The category is part of my **ARC-enabled** static library that I ship on every application I create. It's been tested several times and I didn't find any problems or leaks.

P.S.: You don't need to use a category like I did if the concerned view is a subclass of yours. In the latter case, just put the method in your subclass and you're good to go.

Comment: This is the best answer. No need for recursion, this version is nicely optimized

Answer (score 13):

I modified [de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921573/de) answer so I can pass any view, button, label etc. to get it's parent `UIViewController`. Here is my code.

```
+(UIViewController *)viewController:(id)view {
    UIResponder *responder = view;
    while (![responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        responder = [responder nextResponder];
        if (nil == responder) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (UIViewController *)responder;
}
```

**Edit Swift 3 Version**

```
class func viewController(_ view: UIView) -> UIViewController {
        var responder: UIResponder? = view
        while !(responder is UIViewController) {
            responder = responder?.next
            if nil == responder {
                break
            }
        }
        return (responder as? UIViewController)!
    }
```

**Edit 2:- Swift Extention**

```
extension UIView
{
    //Get Parent View Controller from any view
    func parentViewController() -> UIViewController {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while !(responder is UIViewController) {
            responder = responder?.next
            if nil == responder {
                break
            }
        }
        return (responder as? UIViewController)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Even though this can technically be solved as *pgb* recommends, IMHO, this is a design flaw. The view should not need to be aware of the controller.

Comment: I'm just not sure how the viewController can be told that one of its view's is going away and it needs to call one of its viewXXXAppear/viewXXXDisappear methods.

Comment: This is the idea behind the Observer pattern. The Observed (the View in this case) should not be aware of its Observers directly. The Observer should only receive the callbacks that they're interested in.

Comment: @mahboudz Your whole premise is wrong. A view controller should *not* call one of its lifecycle methods just because one of its subviews is being removed.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget that you can get access to the root view controller for the window that the view is a subview of. From there, if you are e.g. using a navigation view controller and want to push a new view onto it:

```
    [[[[self window] rootViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

You will need to set up the rootViewController property of the window properly first, however. Do this when you first create the controller e.g. in your app delegate:

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    RootViewController *controller = [[YourRootViewController] alloc] init];
    [window setRootViewController: controller];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [controller release];
    [window addSubview:[[self navigationController] view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that in accordance with [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) since `[[self navigationController] view]` is the "main" (sub)view of the window, the `rootViewController` property of the window has to be set to `navigationController` which controls the "main" view immediately.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon a situation where I have a small component I want to reuse, and added some code in a reusable  view itself(it's really not much more than a button that opens a `PopoverController`).

While this works fine in the iPad (the `UIPopoverController` presents itself, therefor needs no reference to a `UIViewController`), getting the same code to work means suddenly referencing your `presentViewController` from your `UIViewController`. Kinda inconsistent right?

Like mentioned before, it's not the best approach to have logic in your UIView. But it felt really useless to wrap the few lines of code needed in a separate controller.

Either way, here's a swift solution, which adds a new property to any UIView:

```
extension UIView {

    var viewController: UIViewController? {

        var responder: UIResponder? = self

        while responder != nil {

            if let responder = responder as? UIViewController {
                return responder
            }
            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While these answers are technically correct, including Ushox, I think the *approved* way is to implement a new protocol or re-use an existing one. A protocol insulates the observer from the observed, sort of like putting a mail slot in between them. In effect, that is what Gabriel does via the pushViewController method invocation; the view "knows" that it is proper protocol to politely ask your navigationController to push a view, since the viewController conforms to the navigationController protocol. While you can create your own protocol, just using Gabriel's example and re-using the UINavigationController protocol is just fine.

Answer (score 6):

### Two solutions as of **Swift 5.2**:

- More on the functional side
- No need for the `return` keyword now

**Solution 1:**

```swift
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        sequence(first: self) { $0.next }
            .first(where: { $0 is UIViewController })
            .flatMap { $0 as? UIViewController }
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2:**

```swift
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        sequence(first: self) { $0.next }
            .compactMap{ $0 as? UIViewController }
            .first
    }
}
```

- This solution requires iterating through each responder first, so may not be the most performant.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's "bad" idea to find out who is the view controller for some cases. What could be a bad idea is to save the reference to this controller as it could change just as superviews change.
In my case I have a getter that traverses the responder chain.

//.h

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController * viewController;
```

//.m

```
- (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    for (UIResponder * nextResponder = self.nextResponder;
         nextResponder;
         nextResponder = nextResponder.nextResponder)
    {
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
            return (UIViewController *)nextResponder;
    }

    // Not found
    NSLog(@"%@ doesn't seem to have a viewController". self);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4

(more concise than the other answers)

```
fileprivate extension UIView {

  var firstViewController: UIViewController? {
    let firstViewController = sequence(first: self, next: { $0.next }).first(where: { $0 is UIViewController })
    return firstViewController as? UIViewController
  }

}
```

My use case for which I need to access the view first `UIViewController`: I have an object that wraps around `AVPlayer` / `AVPlayerViewController` and I want to provide a simple `show(in view: UIView)` method that will embed `AVPlayerViewController` into `view`. For that, I need to access `view`'s `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest do while loop for finding the viewController.

```
-(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    UIResponder *nextResponder =  self;

    do
    {
        nextResponder = [nextResponder nextResponder];

        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
            return (UIViewController*)nextResponder;

    } while (nextResponder != nil);

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but rather makes an assumption about the intent of the question.

If you have a view and in that view you need to call a method on another object, like say the view controller, you can use the NSNotificationCenter instead.

First create your notification string in a header file

```
#define SLCopyStringNotification @"ShaoloCopyStringNotification"
```

In your view call postNotificationName:

```
- (IBAction) copyString:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SLCopyStringNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then in your view controller you add an observer.  I do this in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(copyString:)
                                                 name:SLCopyStringNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Now (also in the same view controller) implement your method copyString: as depicted in the @selector above.

```
- (IBAction) copyString:(id)sender
{
    CalculatorResult* result = (CalculatorResult*)[[PercentCalculator sharedInstance].arrayTableDS objectAtIndex:([self.viewTableResults indexPathForSelectedRow].row)];
    UIPasteboard *gpBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [gpBoard setString:result.stringResult];
}
```

I'm not saying this is the right way to do this, it just seems cleaner than running up the first responder chain.  I used this code to implement a UIMenuController on a UITableView and pass the event back up to the UIViewController so I can do something with the data.

Answer (score 3):

It's surely a bad idea and a wrong design, but I'm sure we can all enjoy a Swift solution of the best answer proposed by @Phil_M:

```
static func firstAvailableUIViewController(fromResponder responder: UIResponder) -> UIViewController? {
    func traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(responder: UIResponder) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = responder.nextResponder() {
            if let nextResp = nextResponder as? UIViewController {
                return nextResp
            } else {
                return traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(nextResponder)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    return traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(responder)
}
```

If your intention is to do simple things, as showing a modal dialog or tracking data, that doesn't justify the use of a protocol. I personally store this function in an utility object, you can use it from anything that implement the UIResponder protocol as:

```
if let viewController = MyUtilityClass.firstAvailableUIViewController(self) {}
```

All credit to @Phil_M

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm late here. But in this situation I don't like category (pollution). I love this way:

```
#define UIViewParentController(__view) ({ \
UIResponder *__responder = __view; \
while ([__responder isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) \
__responder = [__responder nextResponder]; \
(UIViewController *)__responder; \
})
```

Comment: I'd argue a global macro not scoped to a specific class' category is more pollution :P

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 version**

```
extension UIView {
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Usage example

```
 if let parent = self.view.parentViewController{

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Swiftier solution

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        for responder in sequence(first: self, next: { $0.next }) {
            if let viewController = responder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. I'm not sure it's more swifty though. Swift is yet-another-can't-decide-which-of-multiple-paradigms-it-wants-to-be-married-to languages. In this case, you have a nice demonstration of a more functional approach (the `sequence` bit). So if "swifty" means "more functional", then I guess it's more swifty.

Answer (score 2):

Updated version for swift 4 : Thanks for @Phil_M and @paul-slm

```
static func firstAvailableUIViewController(fromResponder responder: UIResponder) -> UIViewController? {
    func traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(responder: UIResponder) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = responder.next {
            if let nextResp = nextResponder as? UIViewController {
                return nextResp
            } else {
                return traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(responder: nextResponder)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    return traverseResponderChainForUIViewController(responder: responder)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To Phil's answer:

In line:  `id nextResponder = [self nextResponder];`  if self(UIView) is not a subview of ViewController's view, if you know hierarchy of self(UIView) you can use also: `id nextResponder = [[self superview] nextResponder];`...

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to upload this to the App Store, you can also use a private method of UIView.

```
@interface UIView(Private)
- (UIViewController *)_viewControllerForAncestor;
@end

// Later in the code
UIViewController *vc = [myView _viewControllerForAncestor];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    let s = sequence(first: self) { $0.next }
    return s.compactMap { $0 as? UIViewController }.first
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would probably be considered kind of bogus but I had a similar situation as mayoneez (I wanted to switch views in response to a gesture in an EAGLView), and I got the EAGL's view controller this way:

```
EAGLViewController *vc = ((EAGLAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).viewController;
```

Comment: Please rewrite your code as follows: `EAGLViewController *vc = [(EAGLAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate viewController];`.

Comment: The problem is not with the dot syntax, but with types. In Objective C to declare an object you write `ClassName *object` - with an asterisk.

Comment: Oops...  that's actually what I had, but the StackOverflow HTML widget thingy looks like it thought the asterisk meant italics... I changed it to a code block, now it displays correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a case when the observed needs to inform the observer.

I see a similar problem where the UIView in a UIViewController is responding to a situation and it needs to first tell its parent view controller to hide the back button and then upon completion tell the parent view controller that it needs to pop itself off the stack.

I have been trying this with delegates with no success.

I don't understand why this should be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is to have your own view class and add a property of the view controller in the view class. Usually the view controller creates the view and that is where the controller can set itself to the property. Basically it is instead of searching around (with a bit of hacking) for the controller, having the controller to set itself to the view - this is simple but makes sense because it is the controller that "controls" the view.

Answer (score 0):

To get the controller of a given view, one can use UIFirstResponder chain.

```
customView.target(forAction: Selector("viewDidLoad"), withSender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who love the good old cycles

```
public func viewController()->UIViewController?{
    var responder:UIResponder? = self;
    while case let curr? = responder, !(curr is UIViewController){
        responder = curr.next;
    }
    return responder as? UIViewController;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your rootViewController is UINavigationViewController, which was set up in AppDelegate class, then

```
    + (UIViewController *) getNearestViewController:(Class) c {
NSArray *arrVc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] childViewControllers];

for (UIViewController *v in arrVc)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:c])
    {
        return v;
    }
}

return nil;}
```

Where c required view controllers class.

USAGE:

```
     RequiredViewController* rvc = [Utilities getNearestViewController:[RequiredViewController class]];
```

Answer (score -5):

There is no way.

What I do is pass the UIViewController pointer to the UIView (or an appropriate inheritance). I'm sorry I can't help with the IB approach to the problem because I don't believe in IB.

To answer the first commenter: sometimes you do need to know who called you because it determines what you can do. For example with a database you might have read access only or read/write ...

Comment: What does that mean - "I don't believe in IB" ?  I've launched it, it certainly exists.

Comment: You need a better grasp of fun and abstraction, especially with regards to the English language. It means I don't like it.

Comment: I don't like avocados. But I bet I can help someone make guacamole. It can be done in IB, so obviously your answer of "there is no way" is incorrect. Whether you like IB or not is irrelevant.