# How do you access a UIViewController function from within a UICollectionCell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a function within a UICollectionViewCell that requires access to the
hosting UIViewController.  Currently 'makeContribution()' can't be accessed:

[image]

What is the proper way of accessing the host UIViewController that has the desired function?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the insightful responses, here's the solution via *delegation*:

[image]

...

[image]

...

[image]

...

[image]

```
{makeContribution}
```

Comment: Great. Delegates  ... YEAH !

Answer (score 1):

This is a mildly controversial question - the answer depends a little on your philosophy about MVC. Three (of possibly many) options would be:

1. **Move the `@IBAction` to the view controller.** Problem solved, but it might not be possible in your case.
2. **Create a delegate.** This would allow the coupling to be loose - you could create a `ContributionDelegate` protocol with the `makeContribution()` method, make your view controller conform to it, and then assign the view controller as a `weak var contributionDelegate: ContributionDelegate?` in your cell class. Then you just call:

   ```
   contributionDelegate?.makeContribution()
   ```
3. **Run up the `NSResponder` chain.** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372977/given-a-view-how-do-i-get-its-viewcontroller) has a Swift extension on `UIView` that finds the first parent view controller, so you could use that:

   ```
   extension UIView {
       func parentViewController() -> UIViewController? {
           var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
           while true {
               if parentResponder == nil {
                   return nil
               }
               parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
               if parentResponder is UIViewController {
                   return (parentResponder as UIViewController)
               }
           }
       }
   }

   // in your code:
   if let parentVC = parentViewController() as? MyViewController {
       parentVC.makeContribution()
   }
   ```

Comment: The Delegation route appears to the best paradigm.
I'm going to file it in my EverNote™ docs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, CollectionView or TableView?

Anyway, Set your `ViewController` as a delegate of the cell. like this:

```
@objc protocol ContributeCellDelegate {
     func contributeCellWantsMakeContribution(cell:ContributeCell)
}

class ContributeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // ...

    weak var delegate:ContributeCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func contributeAction(sender:UISegmentedControl) {
        let isContribute = (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)

        if isContribute {
            self.delegate?.contributeCellWantsMakeContribution(self)
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, ContributeCellDelegate {

    // ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        cell = ...

        if cell = cell as? ContributeTableViewCell {
            cell.delegate = self
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: ContributeCellDelegate methods

    func contributeCellWantsMakeContribution(cell:ContributeCell) {
        // do your work.
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the Delegation paradigm.  I had to do some minor changes per compiler request (see my Answer post). - Thanks.