# Access UIViewController from Utility Class

Tags: ios, swift

**Background:**

I am trying to organize my code for reuse. I like to keep a Utility class that handles all my button-clicking logic on Android, and am trying to do something similar with iOS.

I have a file called `ButtonClicks` with a static method `ClickAction`.

From a custom `UIButton` that I extended to add some data, I use the  `#selector` inside the `UIViewController`.

Inside View Controller:

```
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

// ...

```
@objc func onClick(sender: Button){
    ButtonClicks.ClickAction(Button: sender)
}
```

This works pretty much as expected, with the exception of transitioning to new `UIViewControllers` when needed.

**Question:**

How can I open a new modal `UIViewController` from a utility class?

I'm currently passing a view object, so I have tried the following within the ButtonClicks class:

```
Class ButtonClicks {

static func ClickAction(Button: Button) {

...
// logic for sorting out which action to take
...

        let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
        modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical

        Button.superview?.window?.rootViewController?.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code starts a view controller that covers the entire screen in black, ignoring the `.formSheet` parameter and leaving the app covered in a black screen. It does `print()` logic from the `ModalViewController` to the debug area though.

Changing the presentationtyle to `.partialCurl` gives this error:

> Application tried to present UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl to or
>   from non-fullscreen view controller

Comment: what about passing your current view controller into the function so it can be used for presenting?

Comment: so pass (Button: Button, UIViiewController: View) or something to the function? I'll try that. Do UI components not keep any reference to their view controllers?

Comment: UIViews dont (and should not) keep this reference because they're supposed to be context-independent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372977/given-a-view-how-do-i-get-its-viewcontroller

Comment: It works and is easier than I thought it would be. Write it as an answer and I'll up vote it. Vielen Danke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your UIViewController to the onclick function such as:

```
 static func ClickAction(Button: Button, viewController: UIViewController) {
     //...
     viewController.present(...
}
```