# iOS - Does UIView belong to a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a bunch of subViews in my ViewController.

In the last layer I have a UIView, and from this view I want to call superview and go up until I find the UIView that belongs to my ViewController.

Is it possible to find out whether a UIView belongs to a ViewController or not?

```
UIView *someView = self.superView;

while (true)
{
   if (someView BELONGS TO VIEWCONTROLLER)
   {
      // Now we know this view belongs to a VIewController
      break;
   }

   someView = someView.superView;
}
```

Comment: There is a category written for UIView which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone/3732812#3732812

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Get to UIViewController from UIView on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is about finding the view that belongs to a view controller, not finding the view controller for a given view.

Comment: Hmm, might want to look into UIView tags, could help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to find out if a certain view is in the hierarchy managed by a view controller and you have a pointer to the view controller:

```
BOOL belongsToController = [aView isDescendantOfView:viewController.view];
```

Alternatively, if you want to find out if a certain view is the *root* of the hierarchy managed by the view controller but you don't have a pointer to the view controller, you can traverse the responder chain. According to the `UIResponder`'s [nextResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/nextResponder) documentation:

> `UIView` implements this method by returning the `UIViewController` object that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)

Therefore, if the next responder of a certain view is a `UIViewController`, that view must be the view associated with the view controller.

```
if ([[aView nextResponder] isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
    // aView is the root of the view hierarchy managed by the view controller
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Vlad's and albertamg's approaches are correct as well. However you can also traverse the responder chain

```
  for (UIView* next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
      UIViewController *theControllerThatYouWANT = (UIViewController*)nextResponder;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

try going up in the hierarchy of views and check if current view object is the same as your controller's view

Code would be something like this: (wrote in textEdit, don't have dev tools here, sorry if any mistakes)

```
-(BOOL)view:(UIView *)aView belongsToController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  BOOL belongsToController = NO;
  UIView *someView = [aView superView];
  while (someView != nil) {
    if (viewController.view == someView) {
        belongsToController = YES;
    }
    someView = [someView superView];
  }
  return belongsToController;
}
```

just tested it and it works for me. I hope it was helpfull.
Vlad

Comment: `[aView isDescendantOfView:viewController.view]`

Comment: didn't see that in the headers till now :) Thanks for pointing it out