# How to access mainViewController methods from custom object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've tried the various suggestions from other posts and still can't seem to get this working properly.

Here is my workflow.

```
AppDelegate.m
#import CustomObject.h     // cocoaAsyncSocket wrapper with delegates

  - create customObject[[alloc] init];


mainViewController.m
 - (IBAction)connectDisconnect
 {
    // Access our custom object inside the TPAppDelegate class object.
    TPAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.customObject connectToIP:host port:port timeout:10.0];


customObject.m
#import mainViewController.h

     // custom object delegate
     - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
     {
        // Access methods and properties inside 'mainViewController' class object.
       mainViewController *mainView = (mainViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];

       // call method
       [mainView textViewLog:@"Hello"];
      .
      .
     }



    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication textViewLog:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x188750'
```

The goal is to get my customObject call a method in the mainViewController.

What am I missing?
Or am I going about it completely wrong?

Comment: Why not use a Notification to tell what every object is listing that it needs to update? [`NSnotificationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you ask `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in this line

```
mainViewController *mainView = (mainViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

you got UIApplication instance. Ofcource it's not a `mainViewController`.

I see a few solutions here:

1. pass pointer to your mainViewController to method in customObject
2. implement delegate pattern: define CustomObjectDelegate protocol, add delegate property to CustomObject, set mainViewController as delegate, work with mainViewController from CustomObject as with it delegate.
3. If delegate already used in CustomObject for something else, than you could create delegate's analog (for example as UITableView has delegate and dataSource)
4. create some property (i.e. `mainViewController`) in your application delegate class and set mainViewController to it. Than from anywhere you could ask application delegate as `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and get your `mainViewController` like `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] mainViewController]`.

Comment: I just implemented #4.  :)  Good list of options.  Thank you.  Is there a preference in terms of which one of these is also considered as 'best practice'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a protocol and delegate method

First create object of `mainView` then create customObject's instance 
create a `protocol` and implement it in your `customObject` class and after creating the `customObject` set the delegate as `mainView`. 
 Implement protocol methods in `mainView` then you can call a protocol method from `customObject` that will invoke the delegate method in `mainView`. 
from the delegate method in `mainView` you can call any method that belongs to `mainView`

In your code,
This line have issues:

```
   mainViewController *mainView = (mainViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

[UIApplication sharedApplication]; does not gives you any controller. 


sharedApplication
Returns the singleton application instance.

- (UIApplication *)sharedApplication

Return Value
The application instance is created in the UIApplicationMain function.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I've used successfully is the UIKitCategories approach from:

[Get to UIViewController from UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone)