# Adding UIViewController on half screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm trying to add an UIViewController that i created, but i want it to be a half of the screen size.

I'm using this code:

```
myController *tmController = [[myControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"myController" bundle:nil];
    tmController .view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 100);
    [appDelegate.viewController presentModalViewController:tmController animated:YES];
```

but i see it on all the screen, what is wong with my code?

Comment: On which half do u want can u please elaborate ?

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you are trying to show it modally. Try adding your controller's view as a subview of the window and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can achieve this by category file.....

**.h file :**

```
#define kSemiModalAnimationDuration   0.5
#define kSemiModalDidShowNotification @"kSemiModalDidShowNotification"
#define kSemiModalDidHideNotification @"kSemiModalDidHideNotification"
#define kSemiModalWasResizedNotification @"kSemiModalWasResizedNotification"
@interface UIViewController (KNSemiModal)

-(void)presentSemiViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
-(void)presentSemiView:(UIView*)vc;
-(void)dismissSemiModalView;
-(void)resizeSemiView:(CGSize)newSize;

@end
```

**.m file:**

```
    #import "UIViewController+KNSemiModal.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @interface UIViewController (KNSemiModalInternal)
    -(UIView*)parentTarget;
    -(CAAnimationGroup*)animationGroupForward:(BOOL)_forward;
    @end

    @implementation UIViewController (KNSemiModalInternal)

    -(UIView*)parentTarget {
      // To make it work with UINav & UITabbar as well
      UIViewController * target = self;
      while (target.parentViewController != nil) {
        target = target.parentViewController;
      }
      return target.view;
    }

    -(CAAnimationGroup*)animationGroupForward:(BOOL)_forward {
      // Create animation keys, forwards and backwards
      CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
      t1.m34 = 1.0/-900;
      t1 = CATransform3DScale(t1, 0.95, 0.95, 1);
      t1 = CATransform3DRotate(t1, 15.0f*M_PI/180.0f, 1, 0, 0);

      CATransform3D t2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
      t2.m34 = t1.m34;
      t2 = CATransform3DTranslate(t2, 0, [self parentTarget].frame.size.height*-0.08, 0);
      t2 = CATransform3DScale(t2, 0.8, 0.8, 1);

      CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
      animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t1];
      animation.duration = kSemiModalAnimationDuration/2;
      animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
      animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
      [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];

      CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
      animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:(_forward?t2:CATransform3DIdentity)];
      animation2.beginTime = animation.duration;
      animation2.duration = animation.duration;
      animation2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
      animation2.removedOnCompletion = NO;

      CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
      group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
      group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
      [group setDuration:animation.duration*2];
      [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:animation,animation2, nil]];
      return group;
    }
    @end

    @implementation UIViewController (KNSemiModal)

    -(void)presentSemiViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
      [self presentSemiView:vc.view];
    }

    -(void)presentSemiView:(UIView*)view {
      // Determine target
      UIView * target = [self parentTarget];

      if (![target.subviews containsObject:view]) {
        // Calulate all frames
        CGRect sf = view.frame;
        CGRect vf = target.frame;
        CGRect f  = CGRectMake(0, vf.size.height-sf.size.height, vf.size.width, sf.size.height);
        CGRect of = CGRectMake(0, 0, vf.size.width, vf.size.height-sf.size.height);

        // Add semi overlay
        UIView * overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:target.bounds];
        overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        // Take screenshot and scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(target.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        [target.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIImageView * ss = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [overlay addSubview:ss];
        [target addSubview:overlay];

        // Dismiss button
        // Don't use UITapGestureRecognizer to avoid complex handling
        UIButton * dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissSemiModalView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        dismissButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        dismissButton.frame = of;
        [overlay addSubview:dismissButton];

        // Begin overlay animation
        [ss.layer addAnimation:[self animationGroupForward:YES] forKey:@"pushedBackAnimation"];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kSemiModalAnimationDuration animations:^{
          ss.alpha = 0.5;
        }];

        // Present view animated
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, vf.size.height, vf.size.width, sf.size.height);
        [target addSubview:view];
        view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -2);
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        view.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];
        view.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kSemiModalAnimationDuration animations:^{
          view.frame = f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          if(finished){
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSemiModalDidShowNotification
                                                                object:self];
          }
        }];
      }
    }

    -(void)dismissSemiModalView {
      UIView * target = [self parentTarget];
      UIView * modal = [target.subviews objectAtIndex:target.subviews.count-1];
      UIView * overlay = [target.subviews objectAtIndex:target.subviews.count-2];
      [UIView animateWithDuration:kSemiModalAnimationDuration animations:^{
        modal.frame = CGRectMake(0, target.frame.size.height, modal.frame.size.width, modal.frame.size.height);
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [overlay removeFromSuperview];
        [modal removeFromSuperview];
      }];

      // Begin overlay animation
      UIImageView * ss = (UIImageView*)[overlay.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
      [ss.layer addAnimation:[self animationGroupForward:NO] forKey:@"bringForwardAnimation"];
      [UIView animateWithDuration:kSemiModalAnimationDuration animations:^{
        ss.alpha = 1;
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSemiModalDidHideNotification
                                                              object:self];
        }
      }];
    }

    - (void)resizeSemiView:(CGSize)newSize {
      UIView * target = [self parentTarget];
      UIView * modal = [target.subviews objectAtIndex:target.subviews.count-1];
      CGRect mf = modal.frame;
      mf.size.width = newSize.width;
      mf.size.height = newSize.height;
      mf.origin.y = target.frame.size.height - mf.size.height;
      UIView * overlay = [target.subviews objectAtIndex:target.subviews.count-2];
      UIButton * button = [[overlay subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
      CGRect bf = button.frame;
      bf.size.height = overlay.frame.size.height - newSize.height;
      [UIView animateWithDuration:kSemiModalAnimationDuration animations:^{
        modal.frame = mf;
        button.frame = bf;
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSemiModalWasResizedNotification
                                                              object:self];
        }
      }];
    }

    @end

    #pragma mark - 

    // Convenient category method to find actual ViewController that contains a view
    // Adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone

    @implementation UIView (FindUIViewController)
    - (UIViewController *) containingViewController {
      UIView * target = self.superview ? self.superview : self;
      return (UIViewController *)[target traverseResponderChainForUIViewController];
    }

    - (id) traverseResponderChainForUIViewController {
      id nextResponder = [self nextResponder];
      BOOL isViewController = [nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]];
      BOOL isTabBarController = [nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]];
      if (isViewController && !isTabBarController) {
        return nextResponder;
      } else if(isTabBarController){
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = nextResponder;
        return [tabBarController selectedViewController];
      } else if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        return [nextResponder traverseResponderChainForUIViewController];
      } else {
        return nil;
      }
    }

    @end

#pragma mark - 

// Convenient category method to find actual ViewController that contains a view
// Adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone

@implementation UIView (FindUIViewController)
- (UIViewController *) containingViewController {
  UIView * target = self.superview ? self.superview : self;
  return (UIViewController *)[target traverseResponderChainForUIViewController];
}

- (id) traverseResponderChainForUIViewController {
  id nextResponder = [self nextResponder];
  BOOL isViewController = [nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]];
  BOOL isTabBarController = [nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]];
  if (isViewController && !isTabBarController) {
    return nextResponder;
  } else if(isTabBarController){
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = nextResponder;
    return [tabBarController selectedViewController];
  } else if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
    return [nextResponder traverseResponderChainForUIViewController];
  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}

@end
```

and the call statement....

```
 KNFirstViewController *view=[[KNFirstViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentSemiView:view.view];
```

see the example project [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01r89l9ijwm7rpt/SemiModalViewController.zip)

Comment: Note : all credit goes to Kent Nguyen,  i just used this category in my project...