# How to add UIViewController as target for a programmatically added subview like in IB

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, action, subview, target

When adding UIViews in Xcode's interface builder you can use Ctrl+drag to create a target-action to the UIViewController that holds that view. You can also do that to any subviews you add using IB.

If a subview is created and added programmatically in awakeFromNib is there a way to add the target-action from it to the view controller right there or do you have to first create the subview in awakeFromNib and later create the target-action using the view controller as a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

If its created from scratch, you have to bind events manually.

If however it's loaded from another NIB, there're at least 2 options:

1. You can get a uiviewcontroller from view, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732812/126995 Then you can pass the VC to the [loadNibNamed:owner:options:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007485-CH1-SW5) method.
2. In the IB, you can change the type of the root view from `UIView` into your custom UIView-derived class, and bind actions and outlets from the subviews to the NIB's root view.