# Trigger a method in UIViewController from its View

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with its `UIView` which contains a `UIButton`. I want to trigger a method in `UIViewController` on button click event.
Keeping reference of `UIViewController` doesn't seem to be a good idea like the following link says:
[Get to UIViewController from UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone)

So I want to achive this using a delegate. Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: you have your custom view that you add it in your view controller right?

Comment: right..its my custom view which i added while initializing viewcontroller

Comment: you can use protocol to achieve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this

**CustomView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CustomViewDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)didButtonPressed;

@end

 @interface CustomView : UIView

  @property (assign) id<CustomViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**CustomView.m**

```
#import "CustomView.h"
@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //[self addSubview:titleLbl];
    UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50);
    [button addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(didButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"pressMe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:button];


}
return self;
}
```

in your **ViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView
 {
  [super loadView];
  CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  view.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:view];

 }
```

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for.....This is the right way to achieve functionality asked in the question using delegate :)

Comment: It's much simpler than this and you don't even need a delegate to do it. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the responder chain was built for. When you add a target to your button, just supply `nil` for the target:

```
[mySpecialButton addTarget:nil 
                 action:@selector(mySpecialButtonTapped:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The `nil` target basically means "send `mySpecialButtonTapped:` to any object in the responder chain that can handle it".

Now you can handle this selector anywhere in the responder chain, which includes the button itself, its containing view, its containing view controller, the UIApplication, and finally your AppDelegate. Just place this method in the object most appropriate for your needs:

```
- (void)mySpecialButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog("My special button was tapped!");
}
```

You don't need delegates or callback blocks (as in the accepted answer) if you just want to bubble a message up.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you expected something more fundamental then just pass some button action to controller.
I always follow MVC pattern in case of model/view/controller collaboration. It resolve your issue and many other. And I want to share my experience.

1. Separate controller from view and model: don't put all of the "business logic" into view-related classes; this makes the code very unusable. Make controller classes to host this code, but ensure that the controller classes don't make too many assumptions about the presentation.
2. Define callback APIs with `@protocol`, using `@optional` if not all the methods are required.
3. For view define protocol like `<view class name>Protocol` (example NewsViewProtocol).  For controller define delegate like `<view class name>Delegate` (example NewsViewDelegate) and dataSource like `<view class name>DataSource` (example NewsViewDataSource). Keep all this @protocols in one separate file named `<view class name>Protocol.h` (example NewsViewProtocol.h)

### Short example:

**Contents of NewsView.h**

```
//
// NewsView.h
@interface NewsView : UIView <NewsViewProtocol> {
@protected
     NSObject* delegate_;
     NSObject* dataSource_;
}
@end
```

**Contents of NewsController.h and .m**

```
//
// NewsController.h
@interface NewsController : UIViewController <NewsViewDataSource, NewsViewDelegate> {
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView<NewsViewProtocol>* customView;
@end

@implementation NewsController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.customView = (UIView<NewsViewProtocol>*)self.view;
    [self.customView setDelegate:self];
    [self.customView setDataSource:self];
}
@end
```

**Contents of NewsViewProtocol.h**

```
//
// NewsViewProtocol.h
@protocol NewsViewProtocol;

@protocol NewsViewDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)someAction;
- (void)newsView:(UIView<NewsViewProtocol>*)newsView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@protocol NewsViewDataSource<NSObject>
@required
- (id)newsView:(UIView<NewsViewProtocol>*)newsView itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInNewsView:(UIView<NewsViewProtocol>*)newsView section:(NSInteger)section;
- (BOOL)newsView:(UIView<NewsViewProtocol>*)newsView shouldDisplaySection:(NSInteger)section;
@end

@protocol NewsViewProtocol<NSObject>
@required

//Never retain delegate instance into implementation of this method
- (void)setDelegate:(NSObject<NewsViewDelegate>*)delegate;
//Never retain delegate instance into implementation of this method
- (void)setDataSource:(NSObject<NewsViewDataSource>*)dataSource;
- (void)reload;
@end
```

You may consider that it is redundant. In simple view controller, YES. But if you develop very complex screen with huge amount of data then it gives you some advantages as:

- Helps you to separate responsibility between view and controller.
- Keeps your code clear.
- Makes you code more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Life is easy in xCode.

At the very beginning be sure that your xib View (the one with your button inside it) is associated to the right ViewController class. Which can be the default ViewController class that comes with a new project or your custom one.

After this, here comes the magic trick! Separate your view into 2 panel. The goal is to see your xib and your viewController code (the .m file). Now press the control key of your keyboard and drag your UIButton to the code. Select IBAction. It will generate something you can call a "listener" in other language. Go to the core code of your View Controller and complete the method!

Easy as that! Have fun :)

Comment: Thank You! but its not true in every case

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need delegates for this - it is how UIButtons are intended to be used.  Just control-click and drag from your button to the .m file for your UIViewController.  This will create a new method.  From there, you can either make a call to the method you wrote or just copy-paste what you have into the new method.

Comment: @ancode: um, ok, in that case I think you have to use `@selector`s.  I've never done it that way, so I don't remember the exact syntax, but I think that's what it involved.

Comment: selector would work only in the case when you have the reference to the object which contains the method .....I don't have the reference to the object :)

Answer (score -1):

To add a button programmatically, in myViewController.m

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,21)];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[yourView addSubview:yourButton];
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically).

Comment: as a said here self is not the target ...ViewController of self is the traget

Comment: @ancode: So you're subclassing UIView, and creating a UIButton there?  That's not really the typical way to do this.  Is there a specific reason why you can't create the button when you create the view with your view controller, then add the button as a subview of your view?  (see edit)

Comment: view can be used by many view controller! if i add button in ViewController then i have to do it in every other view controller who wants the same view

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in your selector specify the action

```
- (IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender {
     //Action to perform
}
```