# Adding UIView with its own UIViewController on top of another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to bring up a `UIView` on top of another `UIView`. I want to do this in a way such that the child view will have its own `UIViewController`. Is this possible?

So I should be able to add a button to the child view:

```
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
...
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

`closeMe`  being a method in the child view's ViewController.

In my test code, when the user taps the close button, it crashes with an undefined selector because the parent view's ViewController has no `closeMe` method.

Edit:

Sorry, I mentioned the `closeMe` method only as an example. There are many other methods I need to support with this child view (e.g. handle view rotations), and my goal of the child view having its own ViewController is to encapsulate.

Comment: You can remove the child view using [childview removeFromSupreview]

Comment: what happens if you put the child as the target instead of putting `self`?

Comment: change the addTarget: parameter to whichever view controller implements the method closeMe

Comment: OP UPDATE: found out why it was crashing. The selector was undefined simply because the child viewcontroller was a local variable in the method that created it. When the method exits, the child viewcontroller gets deallocated, hence selector fails. Moving the child viewcontroller to a strong ivar of the parent viewcontroller made this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-->Make your ChildView With custom view that is the subclass of UIView.
-->Add this custom view as a child view in your view
-->And then use `Protocol` to achieve your task.

Comment: After further learning, I think there is no good way to do what I want to do. I think this answer is the best answer, so I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It wounds like you are trying to create a modalView?

Here's a straight forward example of modalViews: http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

What I also like to do is pop all of my viewControllers in a NSMutableArray and make that a property (nonatomic, retain) so you can easily access them from pretty much anywhere in the app through hierarchal means.

Comment: I didn't specify this in my original post, but I don't want a modal presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your child view is a custom view, then you can use delegate/protocol. You dont want separate view controller.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361391/trigger-a-method-in-uiviewcontroller-from-its-view/15363649#15363649)

Answer (score 0):

View controllers and views have a parallel hierarchy.. You can add view controllers as children of one another. Your parent view controller can load its child view controller and then install its child view controller's view in it's own view.

```
UIViewController  --→  UIView
       ↑                 ↑
       | parent vc       | superview
       |                 |
UIViewController  --→  UIView
```

But if you're just adding a subview, you may not need a child view controller.