# how to pass data to the parent class in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegation

I am a beginner in **objective-C**. So please forgive if my question is silly.

In my `root view controller A`, I added a `subview` B.
In b there will be another `subview C`. C contains another `subview D`.
How can I call a method in `A from D`.
I know that we can use **delegates** for passing data to the `parent controller`. 
But my question is that do i need to create delegate which calls `C from D` and another one for call `B from C` and so on? 
Or is there any method which directly calls a method in `A from D`?

Comment: A little more context about what you're trying to do would be helpful. A view really shouldn't be calling a method in a view controller any way.

Comment: When I initilize a `A` from `D`, all the properties will also initializing. So i loose there value. This is my problem

Comment: Are B, C, D `UIView` or `UIViewControllers`?

Comment: All the sub views have its own controllers or all are controlled by your root view controller?

Comment: @manujmv-then B,C and D view are putted on A ViewController ???

Comment: @Anil- all subviews are controlled by the root view controllers

Comment: See my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 3):

> But my question is that do i need to create delegate which calls C from D and another one for call B from C and so on?

The view controller's job is to manage it's view and all of that view's subviews. If you've got a view that needs to send the view controller a message, like a control that needs to send a message somewhere when the user changes its value, then the view controller should be aware that it's there. In such a case, the view controller can take care of setting itself (or some other appropriate object) as said subview's delegate or target when the view hierarchy is loaded, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.needControl.delegate = self;
}
```

That way, the needy control doesn't need to know anything about the object that is its delegate. It's not assuming that the object is the view controller, or its parent view, or anything else. All it cares about is that it has a delegate, and that its delegate implements the necessary methods. And that, in turn, helps you keep your code more flexible and maintainable and maybe even reusable.

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need to create delegate which calls C from D and another one for call B from C and so on?  **No**

You can use a single delegate to call a method in A from D. From your comments i came to know B,C,D are UIView's controlled your root view controller. So the job is easy you need to set a delegate as its root view controller upon creating each sub views.
1. View B is creating from the root view controller itself so **viewB.delegate = self**
2. View C is creating from the view B so **viewC.delegate = self.delegate**
3. Repeat same for view D also

Now all your views are controlled by your delegate rootViewController.
Finally [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361391/trigger-a-method-in-uiviewcontroller-from-its-view/15363649#15363649) will help you to complete your task

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your code so that class D does not know class A exists at all.

There are a few specific techniques that are common in iOS/Mac programming:

- class D has a delegate property, and calls methods on it. Use this when only one object can receive the delegate method, particularly useful for things like a button asking if it should be enabled or disabled right now. Use interface builder to set the delegate of the view to your instance of class A.
- class D should have a "target" property (type `id`) and an "action" property (type `SEL`), and it sends the action message/selector to the target object. useful for when a view has a specific single action that it triggers, such as when a button is pressed, or the user presses Enter in an text field. Use interface builder to set the target and action of the view to your instance of class A.
- class D sends messages and metadata to [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter], and class A tells the notification center that it wants to observe those notifications. Useful when potentially many objects need to be notified when something happened, such as when a text field receives or looses keyboard focus.
- class D has a property or properties sends Key Value Observing notifications whenever it the value of the property changes. Class A would tell the Key Value Observing system that it wants to know whenever a specific property on class D changes. This is useful when you care specifically about some data, such as when the value of a text field changes.

All of these techniques are described in more detail here on stack overflow or in Apple's official documentation.

Class B and C also should not know that class A exists. Class A should be the one that knows how to find the other objects, unless you can use interface builder (the first two options allow that).

Answer (score 0):

Add your `A_viewCon.h` file into your `D_viewCon.h` file

create object of `A_viewCon` and set `@property` and `@synthesize` as properly.

call method of `A_viewCon` in `D_viewCon`write following code.

```
[self.objectOFA_viewCon performSelector:@selector(MethodNameOFA_viewCon) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: problem is that when we initialize a A from D,all the properties of A will also initialized

Comment: @manujmv-then what ?? if OP want to put functionality as he/she needed then this is not a bad idea..:)

Answer (score 0):

U can register Class A to observe a `NSNotification` like ->

`- (void)addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject;`

and post `NSNotifications` from Object of class D like ->

`- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject userInfo:(NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;`

This way u do not need to keep a reference/delegate and still u can communicate between alive objects.