# MFMailComposeViewController Delegate Method Doesn't Get Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates, mfmailcomposer

I have a some kind of action sheet UIView which calls MFMailComposeViewController after tapping a button in it, the MFMailComposeViewController gets called and presented successfully, but it doesn't dismiss when the I tap Cancel and sometimes crashes, I know this is a known problem, but I have tried all the known fixes but it doesn't work for me. That's my code:

**SendFeedback.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface SendFeedback : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

//Useless code to the problem.    

@property (nonatomic, retain) MFMailComposeViewController *feedBackComposer;

@end
```

**SendFeedback.m:**

```
- (void)baseInit
{
    //Useless code to the problem. 

    feedBackComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [feedBackComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [feedBackComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@getibox.com"]];
    [feedBackComposer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [feedBackComposer setSubject:@"What I Love About iBox"];
}
```

And to call the composer: 
    - (void)sendFeedbackComposer
    {
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:feedBackComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

To dismiss it:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)feedBackComposer didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    //This method doesn't get called.

    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

***EDIT:*** So, all the answers provided in this question were correct, and it was all my bad. What I wanted to do is: I had a `UINavigationController` which includes a `UITableView` one of the `cells` in that view should trigger an action sheet which is a `UITableView` by adding it as a `subview`, just like the previous one, this view also includes `cells` and one of them will do an action and it is calling an `MFMailComposeViewController`, which gets called but doesn't dismiss successfully even though I had its delegate set up and all the methods correct, the cause of the problem was the way of calling the `MFMailComposeController`, I first removed from super view that little `UITableView` then presented the `MFMailComposeController`, so when I dismissed the mail composer it crashed without even giving a result, which made me confuse the cause of the crash with the delegate method, fool me.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)removeView
{
    if (self) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{backgroundView.alpha = 0;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                         animations:^{self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 568);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){[self removeFromSuperview];}];
        }];
    }
}
- (void)sendFeedbackComposer
{
    feedBackComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [feedBackComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [feedBackComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@getibox.com"]];
    [feedBackComposer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [feedBackComposer setSubject:@"What I Love About iBox"];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.feedBackComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 2: //That's the index of the MailComposer caller.
            [self removeView];
            [self sendFeedbackComposer];
            break;
        case 6:
            [self removeView];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [feedBackComposer.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Thanks to Stefan Atanasov, Jim, and Vitaly S.

Comment: That `sendFeedbackComposer` method is invoking from other class?

Comment: No, from the same class, it's a UIView.

Comment: Do other implemented delegates from this class works fine?

Comment: Yes, a one is a `UITableViewDelegate`, and it works easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add something to Vitaly S.'s answer (due to lack of reputation I can't comment directly on it, sorry) - the delegate method is called, so the problem is the dismissal. You can try this:

```
[feedBackComposer.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: But the problem isn't the dismissal, it's the method itself; it doesn't get called, not sure if it's because it's a `Subclass UIView` or what, but it's strange that other delegate methods like `UITableViewDelegate` gets called and used easily.

Comment: Hm, strange - I made a simple test project with your code - the delegate method is called the first time, the composer is not dismissed and after that it's never called again (but still it's called once).

Comment: Strange, but how come the method got called but the composer wasn't dismissed? For me, it never gets called, and sometimes it does nothing when I tap Cancel and other times it crashes.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea - this is the test project, it's basically your code, so maybe there's a problem elsewhere  https://github.com/StefanAtanasov/MailComposerTest

Comment: Your code works! I don't what I have done wrong, I'll investigate on that now and inform you.

Comment: It was all my bad, I did something that made all this go wrong, just edit your answer and add your comment to it for me to accept the answer, I will explain what I have done now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that delegate method isn't called? I made a test and it's called, but to dismiss mail composer use such code:

`[feedBackComposer dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];`

Also it's really strange to implement delegates in view implementation, not in view controller

Comment: Yes, it works in `UIViewController` but it doesn't in a `UIView`, I don't know why, I used your code and it gives the same results. I will explain what I'm trying to achieve: I have a `UIViewController` which contains a button that adds that `UIView` as a subview, it's like an action sheet, then one of the buttons in that `UIView` should call the `MFMailComposeViewController`, that's why I'm trying to do it from a `UIView` not a `UIViewController`, any other suggestions about that are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate methods need to be called from the viewController, not from within the UIView.

Your view controller that calls the UIView will have your delegates

```
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

within it's header file.

You need to make a delegate method to pass information from the UIView to the controller, which will in turn call the mail and table delegate methods.

Here is a link to a question that demonstrates how to use a delegate protocol to trigger a method in the view controller from the UIView.

[Trigger a method in UIViewController from its View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361391/trigger-a-method-in-uiviewcontroller-from-its-view)

Hope this helps, Jim

Comment: Oh, I guessed that too! But how come `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` gets called and used successfully? Besides, this `UIView` is a `subclass`, not the `UIView` of the `UIViewController` can I still trigger the method in the `UIViewController`? And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check is it device is configure to send mail by checking MFMailComposeViewController is avail to respond or not.

```
  if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
  //your code
  }
```