# How Do I call a method from a view contained in a view controller ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UIView Subclass`, from the subclass I want to call a method defined in the `UIViewController` which contains it. I do not want to instantiate a new instance of the view controller, because it contains information that I need within the method I am attempting to call. Here is a diagram trying to further clarify:

(UIViewController) MainView --> has method `updateView`

(UIView) SubView ---> Has Button that plays animation and has completion block

I want to call `UpdateView` in the completion block

Comment: This means that your view controller should probably be setting itself as a delegate for your view on view creation, and that your view should be calling this as a delegate method.

Comment: Take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: if you are passing completion block to subView from mainView, then in that block call that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can set up a protocol in your Subview, which can be implemented by your ViewController

Your SubView.h

```
@class SubView;

@protocol SubViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)actionToPromoteToViewController: (NSString *)exampleString isSelected:(BOOL)exampleBool;
@end
```

Then, in your ViewController.h:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <SubViewDelegate>
```

and your ViewController.m, implement the method.

```
- (void)actionToPromoteToViewController: (NSString *)exampleString isSelected:(BOOL)exampleBool{
   // Method Implementation

}
```

Comment: Delegates for sure in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For 'correct' implementation you need a reference to view controller in your `UIView Subclass`:

```
@interface UIViewSubclass : UIView
...
@property UIViewControllerSubclass *viewController;
@end
```

Then set this `viewController` reference to your view controller and use it in completion block.

If you want a local solution (and not to extend `UIViewSubclass` with property) take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732812/326017