# Get superView of custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, superview

I have a custom class `myCustomClass` which is a subclass of `UITextField`. (I'm going to call `myCustomClass` in a `viewControllers` class.)

In `myCustomClass`, I'm trying to check what kind of `viewController` the class that called it is. (`UIViewController`, `UITableViewController` etc.)

I tried:

```
if ([self.superview.nextResponder isKindOfClass[UIViewController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"View Controller");
} else if ([self.superview.nextResponder isKindOfClass[UITableViewController class]) {
    NSLog(@"TableView Controller");
}
```

I only get a result if the `superclass` is a `viewController`. So I did the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.superview.nextResponder);
```

**Results**

UIViewController Class - `ViewController`

UITableViewController Class - `UITableViewCell`

How can I check if it's a UITableViewController?

Comment: I suppose you could ask if the superview isMemberOfClass :UITableViewCell and then you'd know it was in a tableView!

Comment: That did the trick!! Can't believe it was that simple!! Thanks!! Can you please **add** this to your current answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case, you can use `[self.superView isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]` to check if your custom view is inside a table view cell, which (unless you are using tableViewCell in an unusual way!) means that it's being called from a UITableViewController.

More generally, if you wanted to find out the containing view controller, you can recursively walk up the responder chain to find the containing viewController as in the second answer in this post:
[Get to UIViewController from UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview)

It's also important to note that there is a difference between `isKindOfClass:` and  `isMemberOfClass:`

- `isKindOfClass` returns YES if 'the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.'
- `isMemberOfClass` returns YES if ' the receiver is an instance of a given class.'

Therefore, your UITableViewController, which inherits from UIViewController, will answer YES to `isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]`, will your `if` statement to act unexpectedly.  (Though in the example it also didn't work correctly because you still needed to walk up the responder chain further).

So, if you in fact are comparing a UIViewController to a UITableViewController use `-isMemberOfClass` and your logic in the example would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I will keep that in mind! But when I changed it to isMemberOfClass, I still didn't get any results for the tableViewController

Comment: Sorry, I'm re-reading your question and I see that this won't entirely fix the problem.  I think you'll want to keep going up the responder tree until you get to a viewController (by asking -isKindOfClass), and then differentiate between the two type of viewControllers with -isMemberOfClass