# How to show viewcontroller from the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I searched for answers like [Get to UIViewController from UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview) and couple of other answers but was not successful.

My issue is that I have a button in `UIView` lets say `class1` and when I click on that button I want to load another view `class2` which is `UIViewController`, and as I don't get `navigationController` in `class1` I am unable to load the `class2` view.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,
In Advance.

Comment: from where you are showing `UIView` of class1?

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Comment: I am showing class1 from tabbar, whenever the application loads the first tabBarItem is class1 which is default selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `UIViews` should not contain any logic that triggers the flow of app. This is the job of `UIViewControllers`. It's just a way of making the design of your code better and more organized.

One way I often use is to use a `delegate` pattern in my custom UIViews. Here is s simple setup:

In your MyCustomView .h file:

```
@class MyCustomView;

@protocol MyCustomViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)myViewDidTapOnButton:(MyCustomView)myCustomView;
@end


@interface MyCustomView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyCustomViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In your MyCustomView .m file:

```
- (IBAction)didTapMyButton:(id)sender {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myViewDidTapOnButton:)]) {
        [self.delegate myViewDidTapOnButton:self];
    }
}
```

Then in your viewcontroller, which is presenting your view:

interface:

```
@interface MyViewController ()<MyCustomViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myCustomView;
```

and implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myCustomView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)myViewDidTapOnButton:(MyCustomView)myCustomView {
    ... code for presenting viewcontroller ...
}
```

**Note**:
Even if you dont use the parameter `myCustomView` which is sent in this method, its a common pattern and good habit to always send the `sender` of the delegate as the first parameter.

This is also used a lot by Apple, e.g. in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: I tried 'delegate' pattern but i was not able to as i am rookie in ios, if you can provide something which can be more understanding on 'delegate' please.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to hear that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two cases :

- If you are using storyboard then give your NavigationController a
  storyboard id. And create an object of `navigationController` in your
  custom `UIView` class.
- If you have customized the app launching from `AppDelegate` create a
  `public property` of your `navigationController`. From your `UIView` class create an object of appDelegate with `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`. From this object access the `navigationController property`

When you have the `navigationController` object you can push your viewcontroller with:

`[navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: Yes i am having `AppDelegate`  and i also have property of `navigationController`  but when i do `self.navigationController` i don't get the navigation controller.

so I have to call `pushViewController` with the object of `appdelegate`?

Comment: no, viewcontrollers can be pushed only on `navigationController` objects

Comment: I tried the same but its not working, code gets executed but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

First fill storyboard ID with "MyViewController", which is a String field that you can use to create a new ViewController based on that storyboard ViewController. And later access that view controller like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    MyCustomViewController *newvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
   [self presentViewController:newvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ajay for your effort :-) but i have not used storyboards, and i got the solution, which was given by knutigro.

Answer (score 0):

When you click your button,you can do this:

```
YouViewController *yourViewController = [YouViewController new];
[self.view addSubView:yourViewController.view];
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: self.view gives error as property `view` not found in `class1`

Comment: SomeViewController    *someViewController    = [[SomeViewController alloc]initWithTitle:@"Map"];  [self.view addSubView:someViewController.view];

Comment: is there something wrong ? self is current viewController.

Comment: i am totally clueless, why it is not giving me view when i am trying, but the method which @knutigro gave worked well.