# xcode - multiple instances of custom view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, custom-view

I've created a custom UIViewController with storyboard and this is the class:
.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayerViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PlayerNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PlayerImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PlayerNameLabel;

-(void)setPlayerName:(NSString*)PlayerNameString;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "PlayerViewController.h"

@interface PlayerViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerViewController
@synthesize PlayerImage,PlayerNameLabel,PlayerNumber;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)setPlayerName:(NSString *)PlayerNameString{
self.PlayerNameLabel.text=PlayerNameString;
}

@end
```

from main view I create 2 instance of PlayerViewController in order to display 2 custom views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self DrawPlayerWithTag:1];
[self DrawPlayerWithTag:2];
}


- (void)DrawPlayerWithTag:(int)PlayerTag{
PlayerViewController *myPlayerViewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerViewController"];
UIView *myPlayerView=myPlayerViewController.view;
myPlayerView.tag=PlayerTag;
myPlayerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
myPlayerView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height / 2);

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[myPlayerView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


[self.view addSubview:myPlayerView];
[myPlayerViewController setPlayerName:@"NameA"];
```

}

It seems to work.
But, if I want to change the PlayerName, how can refer to view1 rather then view2 after a double tap event, and use the method  setPlayerName?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the callback method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doDoubleTap:)];
```

You can get the tag of the view like this:

```
-(void)doDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
   NSLog(@"%ld", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

You can keep your code and invoke `setPlayerName` with this post [Get to UIViewController from UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview)

But, I suggest this way:

- set target for `gesture` is `myPlayerViewController`

  `UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myPlayerViewController action:@selector(doDoubleTap:)];`
- Keep ref of myPlayerViewController in "main view" by an array like:

  `[arrPlayerView addObject:myPlayerViewController]; /// keep pointing to myPlayerViewController, so it isn't released.`
- Place `(void)doDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture` in `PlayerViewController`

Comment: Hi, it's clear, but as soon as I get the tag, how can I invoke the method setPlayerName? Thank you

Comment: Great, it works perfectly, thank you very much, Beppe

Comment: Hi anthu, i've marked your answer but it seems that we've to wait for my reputation up to 15 befor seeing it effect... Ciao grazie

Comment: @Beppe mark correct is different with upvote. Upvote is the triangle. Mark answer is the check symbol. It is between 2 triangle. :)

Comment: @Beppe And mark correct doesn't require the reputation. :)