# Detect when UIView is added in other UIView which MUST has a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

Is there a notification or callback when a UIView is added in other UIView which has a UIViewController. We can get a UIView's ViewController, if it has one, via nextResponder. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview))

But depending on nextResponder is not reliable, if the UIView is not been added into a View which has ViewController, this method fails. For example, when we are calling from the cell's responder in UITableViewDataSource's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Because by the time of calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the cell being dequeued hasn't been added into UITableView yet. However, we can call that method in `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, because by the time of calling `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, the cell is already being added into TableView.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have `ViewA` which is the view of `ViewControllerA` and you want to add the `ViewB` you can subclass `ViewB`

```
@protocol ViewBDelegate

- (void) viewAddedToSuperview:(ViewB*)sender;

@end

@interface ViewB: UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id< ViewBDelegate > delegate;

@end
@implementation

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    [delegate viewAddedToSuperview:self];
}


@end
```

and in `ViewControllerA` you implements the protocol `ViewBDelegate`.

This is just an example of my idea.

Let me know in the comments it is can help you, otherwise I will try to propose other solutions depending on your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is probably not I am looking for. Maybe there is no perfect solution for this. My problem is that when my 'View' is being added as a subview of some 'View'(as: 'ViewSuper'). If this 'ViewSuper' does not have a UIViewController AND none of 'ViewSuper''s super views has a UIViewController, I don't want to get called. In your case, if ViewA is not the view of a `ViewController`, didMOveToSuperview still get called.